# Woocommerce, не работает кнопка "Купить"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На главной странице есть список товаров, и при клике "Купить" на одном из товаров, в шапке попап-окно сообщает, что товар добавлен, но при наведении на иконку корзины,  показывает что корзина пустая, даже если и были в ней уже товары.
Но дело в том, что на странице отдельного товара кнопка "Купить" нормально работает и товар добавляется в корзину.
Вот код кнопки на главной:

```
<a rel="nofollow" onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', '/preview/add-to-cart');" href="/product-brands/path/?removed_item=1&amp;add-to-cart=116553" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="116553" data-product_sku="13729" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Купить</a>
```

т.е. после клика "купить" корзина очищается почему-то.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: есть ли идеи как исправить?

Comment: А что это за параметр "?removed_item=1" в строке?